# What to implement when "msal:acquireTokenFailure" is thrown?

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I know this should be simple, but a little help would be appreciated; we're all a bit new to using industrial strength typescript packages.

We're building an Angular App and using the @azure/msal-angular library, which for most part works OK; following the tutorials and examples and it generally all make sense.

Apart from what to implement when the "msal:acquireTokenFailure" event is broadcast?

In the ngOnInit() method of our AppComponent we have this line

```
    // Subscriptions and redirects are for jwtTokens
    this.subscription = this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:acquireTokenFailure", () => {
      // ToDo: What should be implemented here?
    });
```

In a few posts to the GitHub page for the project contributors have suggested something along the lines of

```
    // Subscriptions and redirects are for jwtTokens
    this.subscription = this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:acquireTokenFailure", () => {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      this.authService.loginRedirect();
    });
```

Which, as far as   I can, will redirect to an AzuerAD login screen but will lose the underlying call details that we trying to get a Token for.

What looks more useful (in pseudo-code) would be something like

```
// Subscriptions and redirects are for jwtTokens
    this.subscription = this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:acquireTokenFailure", () => {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();

      if (isIE) {
        this.authService.acquireTokenRedirect(userRequest);
      } else {
        this.authService.acquireTokenPopup(userRequest);
      }
    });
```

The question being, is this a valid approach; and where would we recover the userRequest parameters from?

Please, please, don't redirect me to the Microsoft docs; I've spent hours going round in circles following the same links...

Comment: I am looking for an example of this usage also.  The github samples don't seem to deal with expiring tokens, etc.

Comment: It’s still on our ToDo list... currently we’re just happy to have tamed Azure AD into graciously allowing us to sign in without returning reams of exceptions :-(

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Comment: Unfortunately no; we’re just wrapping up some feature work, but planning on going back, updating the packages and trying again. The Microsoft identity / msal packages seem to be evolving towards .net 5 so maybe breaking changes which resolve the issues...?

Comment: I am using this code for redirecting to login when token is expired:

const sub = this.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:acquireTokenFailure', x => {
      sub.unsubscribe();
      console.error('acquireTokenFailure :: token is expired.')
      this.authService.loginRedirect();
    });

Comment: @CarlosCruz I tried to use your code (need to do exactly the same) but unfortunately it does not work. I cannot subscribe to msalBroadCastService, I only can subscribe to either msalBroadCastService.inProgress$ or msalBroadCastService.msalSubject$ ... but then it does not work either. Do you have any tip how to make this work? I use Angular13 with RxJs7... is there a difference because of this?

Comment: @CarlosCruz eventually I came up with this code, which works: ````this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$.subscribe({ next: (msalSubject) => { if (msalSubject.eventType === 'msal:acquireTokenFailure') { this.msalService.logout(); }} ````